# How to remove a empty <p></p> in wp caption shortcode?

Tags: captions

I recently added a caption to my image in WordPress and now there is an empty `<p></p>` tag after `<img>` tag. It broke my style.

Can anyone tell how to remove it?

Thanks for the help.

[image: demo]

Comment: Most likely this depends on the theme you are using.

Comment: Blame wpautop. You can hide it with CSS. p:empty { display: none; }

Comment: The empty `<p>` tag is inside the `<div>` tag of the attachment itself so its probably because of your theme. Perhaps it's reserved for the Description field? What's the output when you add a description to your image?

Comment: Is there any Image/attachment related plugin installed? Which might be adding the empty `<p>` tag or altering the attachments.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good practice to override the WordPress native functionality. Instead you can hide the empty elements using CSS

```
p:empty  {
    display: none;
}
```

This will the empty elements.

Answer (score 3):

## Removing `wpautop`:

This is most likely from [`wpautop`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/). To fix that, first write the following CODE in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

If it doesn't solve the issue, that may mean `<p></p>` got into your database *or* you have empty newline inside your `[caption][/caption]` Shortcode. Go to the post & edit out the `<p></p>` or `empty new line` from WordPress editor's `Text` mode.

That should solve your problem.

## Alternative CSS Solution:

You may use CSS CODE to hide `<p></p>` as [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/256111/110572) suggested. However, with that method, it'll still be in your HTML & ***there's no point*** in creating it and then hiding it entirely with CSS. It's better to remove it in that case with the above CODE.

However, if you want to keep `wpautop` for some reason (may be you are using it for formatting somewhere else in the site), then you may target only the `<p></p>` tags within the captions with the following CSS:

```
.wp-caption > p:empty  {
    display: none;
}
```

This will keep the formatting of `wpautop` elsewhere in your site and at the same time solve the display problem for the captions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove this using `str_replace` to replace the p tags with `the_content` filter:

```
function wpse256087_content_filter($content) {

    $content = str_replace( '<p></p>', '', $content );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse256087_content_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the `do_shortcode_tag` hook.

```
function remove_empty_wp_caption_text($output, $tag) {
  if ($tag === 'caption') {
    $output = str_replace('<p class="wp-caption-text"> </p>', '', $output);
  }

  return $output;
}
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'remove_empty_wp_caption_text', 10, 2);
```

What's nice about this approach is that the function won't be ran unless the `[caption]` shortcode is called.